# Java Null Pointer Exception when reading from text file

Tags: java, file-io, nullpointerexception

I am having trouble reading from a text file and i keep getting the error "java null pointer exception"

My read file class is

```
public class readfile {
    private Scanner x;

public void openfile() {
    try {
        x = new Scanner(new File("test2.txt"));
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.println("error");
    }
}

public void readfile() {
    while(x.hasNext()) {
        String a = x.next();
        String b = x.next();
        String c = x.next();

        System.out.printf("%s %s %s",a,b,c);
    }
}
```

and my main class to call these methods is

```
public class InputOut {

public static void main(String[] args) {
   readfile r = new readfile();
   r.openfile();
   r.readfile();
   r.closeFile();
   }

}
```

i get the error when i call the readfile exception so i believe i might not be opening it correctly? I saved the file in the directory where the program is run and has the follwoing format

```
50 issac billy
432 bryan darren
443 rob zombie
```

did i miss something to read files here. I imported the java.io*; class and the java.util class as well. Error occurs at `public void readfile()`

Comment: You have not yet shown us which line throws the NPE, and this is key. No, it's not just key, it's super critical. Please fix this.

Comment: Add your entire exception, including full stack trace, to your post.

Comment: Also, as per the most common cause of this question, often you're looking in the wrong place for your file. Please search this site for similar questions to see how it is done as this is asked **often**.

Comment: unrelated to the question, but importing java.io.* isn't exactly the best idea. You would benefit much more from just importing what you use. See http://javadude.com/articles/importondemandisevil.html for rough explanation as to why.

Comment: put `e.printStackTrace();` into your `catch` block.

Answer (score 3):

Just a quick guess... Your code is

```
while(x.hasNext()) {
    String a = x.next();
    String b = x.next();
    String c = x.next();
```

hence you are checking if ONE element exists (via `hasNext()`). Checking is always a good idead. But then you should read only the next element (via `next()`) and not further without checking again.